Bad circuit breaker panel?
My occasionally used farm cabin had no power when we arrived. Checked the breaker panel, tested the outgoing wires from each breaker. All were dead but one. I tried a new breaker in a couple of slots but got no power from any slot except the only one that worked originally. How can only one slot have power?

Pictures will help.  An off hand guess is most of the panel is rusted away.  If one slot has power(every second breaker down the line), then half of the panel should have power with decent connections.

Can you post photos of the panel?

Call an electrician asap. There could be oxidized buss bars that can cause a fire.
I used to have a condo where the units had breaker boxes in the storage closets on the porches.  Many units had fires started in the breaker box. Mine included.  The boxes being in unconditioned space caused  oxidation on many of the aluminum surfaces, causing resistance and fire.
